# How to update an array from two separate threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I am running two separate threads:

```
List<String> where = new ArrayList<String>();
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MainWatch R1 = new MainWatch("C:\\test", "Thread1");
    R1.start();
    MainWatch R2 = new MainWatch("C:\\test2", "thread2");
    R2.start();
}
```

I want both of them to update the `where` array:

```
public class MainWatch implements Runnable {
    private String location = "";
    private Thread t;
    private String threadName;

    public MainWatch(String l, String threadName) {
        location = l;
        this.threadName = threadName;
    }

    public void start() {
        if (t == null) {
            t = new Thread(this, threadName);
            t.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Where.add(location);
    }
}
```

How do I get those two threads to access the `where` variable on the main thread to both have access to it?

Thanks!

Comment: You can either make a Getter and Setter in main for _Where_, or create your thread in _main_ to keep track of a reference in there rather than in _mainWatch_.

Comment: What actual problem are you having?  What error message do you get?  What line and what is the full text of the error?

Comment: @VinnieS, pass the list as a parameter constructor of `mainWatch` (btw `m` should be capital), similarly to what you did with those two strings.

Comment: The `where` variable is not _on_ any thread.  Threads don't have variables (except for _local_ variables, which can not be accessed by other threads.)  You seem to have declared `where` as an instance variable in whatever class contains your `main()` method.  I don't see any place in your code where you create an instance of that class.  If you don't create any instance of it, then `where` does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to provide your threads with links to your list. To do that, you might want to make `where` a static field.

Second, you need to synchronize access to the list in order not to get `ConcurrentModificationException`.

```
private static List<String> = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MainWatch R1 = new MainWatch("C:\\test", "Thread1", where);
    R1.start();
    MainWatch R2 = new MainWatch("C:\\test2", "thread2", where);
    R2.start();
}

public class MainWatch implements Runnable {
    ...
    private final List<String> where;

    public MainWatch(String loc, String ThreadName, List<String> where) {
        location = loc;
        this.threadName = threadName;
        this.where = where;
    }

    ...
    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized(where) {
            where.add(location);
        }
    }
}
```